# Bitwise AND with 0xFFFFFFFF in Python

Tags: python, binary, hex, bit-manipulation

```
5 & 0xFFFFFFFF # 5
-5 & 0xFFFFFFFF # 4294967291
```

In Python, why bitwise AND a negative number with 0xFFFFFFFF will give a different result? Since 0 & 1 = 0 and 1 & 1 = 1, should bitwise AND a number with 0xFFFFFFFF (11111111111111111111111111111111) keep every digit what it was?

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF is not a negative number in Python. If you were limited to 32-bit integers then it would be. In Python, that's equivalent to +4294967295

Comment: Python integers have no fixed width, so negative numbers are treated as having an infinite number of leading 1s.  By AND-ing with `0xFFFFFFFF`, you're discarding all but the 32 low bits.  Instead of using `0xFFFFFFFF`, just use `-1`.

Comment: Maybe you could and it with the positive number and times it with -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give some more illustration, in python, to get the bit representation of -5 you apply two's complement rule, that is: start from 5, flipped bits, add 1

```
-5 -> 0000....0000000101 (5 in binary) -> 1111....1111111010 (flipped) -> 1111....1111111011 (+1)
```

When you `&` it with `0xFF` you are doing this:

```
  1111....1111111011
& 0000....0011111111
= 000000000011111111 = +255
```

I've used 0xFF but that does not matter since as @Tom Karzes mentioned,

> Python integers have no fixed width, so negative numbers are treated
> as having an infinite number of leading 1s.
> and positive numbers have an infinite number of leadin 0s.